# Share an Internet Connection over three machines

Tags: networking, internet, internet-connection

I want to share my Broadband Internet Connection over three computers. I am having Windows XP on all three machines, a switch and a modem. All my three machines are on LAN. Currently I need to dial-up the connection to connect to the Internet. But only on one pc i can use it. If Internet is connected on one PC then it can't be used on the others. Please help. I tried using ICS but all in vain.

Answer (score -1):

this should get you going with your dialup modem [Microsoft ICS setup](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/expert/crawford_02july01.mspx)